# Figure and Text in separate pages

Tags: formatting, vspace

I am writing up my thesis where a logo has to be placed on a page and I want to put a copyright singly on another page but they squeeze in the same page. I tried using `\vfill` (and `\vspace{\fill}`) but that doesn't seem to work. I tried `\clearpage` which provided me the solution but a blank page after the figure disappears (my text is both-sided and the fig and copyright should appear on the odd page).
[Edit]
The document begins with a title page which I included in the code below

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openright]{report}
\usepackage[top=25mm,bottom=25mm,left=25mm, right=25mm, bindingoffset=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    'This is some cover page with another logo image'
\end{titlepage}
\pagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}
\newpage
\begin{figure}
\topskip0pt
    \vfill
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{logo}
    \vfill
\end{figure}
%--------------------COPYRIGHT-------------------------
\newpage \topskip0pt
\vspace*{\fill}
Copyright \textcopyright \@{} 2021 Author
\vspace*{\fill}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: you should not use `figure` here it is not a float, just use `\includegraphics` directly (then the vfill will  have an effect as well).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle removing the `figure` works and places the logo and the text on separate pages but then the even (blank) pages before and after the logo disappears :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blank page (#2) + logo(#3)

[image: a]

Blank page(#4) + copyright page (#5)

[image: b]

Try this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openright]{report}

\usepackage[top=25mm,bottom=25mm,left=25mm, right=25mm, bindingoffset=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%
\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{titlepage}
\cleardoublepage
\newpage\mbox{}
\vfill
\begin{figure}  
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b} 
\end{figure}
\vfill
\cleardoublepage
%--------------------COPYRIGHT-------------------------
\newpage\mbox{}
\topskip0pt
\vfill
Copyright \textcopyright \@{} 2021 Author
\vfill

\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution worked with an addition of [h!] to the figure. Without [h!], the figure moves to next page with two blank pages ahead of it. Anyways thanks for the help :)